# tuning the kernel parameters of an algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, kernel

I have an own algorithm that uses kernel function to calculate distances. I want to fit the kernel parameters, but I don't know how to do it, since caret package only allow their algorithms (such as SVM, decision trees etc). I would like to know if there is some optimizer function. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have an objective measure of performance on your algorithm (e.g. classification accuracy), try using spearmint. It's a bayesian parameter optimization tool. You can treat your algorithm like a black box and tune the parameters for your kernel.

https://github.com/JasperSnoek/spearmint

Comment: Thanks, is it avaiable in R?

Comment: It's written in python but if you use [rpy2](http://rpy2.bitbucket.org) you can create a python wrapper for your R code.